# What is the reason to use Commanding with ViewModels in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin

I cannot understand this:

> Sometimes, however, the View needs to contain buttons that trigger
>   various actions in the ViewModel. **But the ViewModel must not contain
>   Clicked handlers for the buttons because that would tie the ViewModel
>   to a particular user-interface paradigm**.

What is the reason of commanding?

Comment: Very short example of this reason - is to have `LogicOperation()` method insteand of `ButtonLogicOperation_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` in your view-model.

Answer (score 1):

Clicked handlers are generally events created by **controls**. The handler can be specific to the controls you actually use. For example, you could create your own user controls with an event with a specific **event handler**.

Problem is that you want to seperate your view model with the implementation of your view. We don't want to force the view to use some controls: a `List` or `ObservableCollection` could be viewed in a `ListView`, `ListBox`, `DataGrid`, etc. That said, using click handlers or any handlers will result in forcing the view to use or return these handlers. **This is dependency between your view and view model**.

As a result, we use commanding instead. It removes this dependency since pretty much any controls can use commands and send commands event when a situation is raised (Click, drag, drop, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you a practical answer from my own experience:

- Making your code testable: You can read more about "Unit Testing", but basically they are scenarios written in code, and in these scenarios you're assuming the results. 
  Now because these "Tests" are just c# code, there's no way they can access your page and click the button to test the result. But in the other hand, they can instantiate your ViewModel, and execute the command.
- If you write a ViewModel the proper way, you can reuse these ViewModels in differfent projects in differfent platforms: UWP (Phone,tablet,desktop.hololense,IOT) , Xamarin (iOS, Android, MacOSX).
- Let's say you're writing this page which has a click event (in the code behind) that will submit data to a sever. what will happen if you want to call the same method but this time when the user presses "Enter" in the keyboard?. With Commands, you can easily bind the command to the proper event in the ViewModel